# Where is the source code of F# 3.1.2?

Tags: f#, f#-3.1

I'm trying to build F# myself, the [official instructions](http://fsharp.org/use/linux/) include cloning the repo: `git clone https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp`.

But if you look at the master branch of the repo, you'll see it is still version `3.1.1.25`, for example as stated in [CHANGES.txt](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/CHANGES.txt).

So where can I find build instructions or just the source for 3.1.2? The 3.1 branch is the same as the master branch...

Comment: I am not sure of the precise current status, but when F# 3.0 was open sourced, Microsoft decided the canonical repo should be on CodePlex, with the linux/mono compatible one on Github (personally I think they should have just used the github for everything).  It is possible that the 3.1.2 changes haven't been merged into the github repo.

Comment: I see. Thanks for clearing that up. Guess I'm sticking to 3.1.1 for now. I was really looking forward to finally being able to just use `#!` instead of the `#light`-hack in my scripts though ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The official microsoft fsharp repo is https://visualfsharp.codeplex.com/ . This is the official repo for windows and the compiler/core libraries

the open edition is https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp and is used for packaging of osx, linux ( can build windows too ) and cross platform fix/test

all changes not related to osx/linux packaging are committed first to visualfsharp, and after accepted are merged into open edition

The visualfsharp is merged into open edition after some time. Last time was July 17 with  3.1.1.25 , see [commits of Jul 17](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/commit/20a9d20e7a3752244b03f62147e453db748a08eb)

for info about building visualfsharp see [DEVGUIDE.html](https://visualfsharp.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#DEVGUIDE.html)